# jQuery UI draggable and rotatable parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a div with a bunch of childs rotatable with this plugin: https://github.com/trev/Rotatable

The element is draggable by the built in draggable function in jQuery UI. Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.case .input', function(){
    $(this).draggable({handle:'.drag'});
    $(this).children('.resize.tl').parent().rotatable({ autoHide: false });
});
```

And here is my markup.

```
<div class="case">
    <div class="case_background"></div>
    <div class="case_model">

        <!-- This is loaded by ajax -->
        <div class="input" data-name="'+n+'">
            <div class="drag">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="resize tl">
                <div class="topleft"></div>
            </div>

            <input class="casetext opensans" type="text" name="textfield[]" size="25" value="The text">
        <!-- End of ajax load -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing that is happening is the rotatable plugin does add divs with classes "rotatable-handle ui-draggable" every time you hover it.

How would you solve this? Do you see any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the handle was what I should use.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.case .input, .case .image', function(){
    var tc = $(this);
    tc.rotatable({
        handle:tc.children('.rotate.left, .rotate.right')
    });
    return true;
});



<div class="case">
    <div class="case_background"></div>
    <div class="case_model">

        <!-- This is loaded by ajax -->
        <div class="input" data-name="'+n+'">
            <div class="drag">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rotate left">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rotate right">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>

            <input class="casetext opensans" type="text" name="textfield[]" size="25" value="The text">
        <!-- End of ajax load -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```